# Site iPhone styling

Tags: feature-request

When dba.se is visited using Mobile Safari on the iPhone the site is rendered normally. However, when stackoverflow.com is visited the site presents itself in a cut-down way that is better suited to the device.

Would it be possible to adopt the same styling/functionality on dba.se?

Comment: I don't witness this. Can you give a screenshot? Additionally, down at the bottom is a button that says "Mobile" will you kindly click that and see if you've put your profile into a Desktop mode.

Comment: Oops, I didn't see the option at the bottom of the screen! Apologies.

Comment: Nonsense, this is why we're here :D